Rabbeinu Bachya States That Jonah Curled up and Slept Soundly on the Tossing Ship Because he was Confident that he Would be Saved - How did he Know?
Jonah was told to go to Ninveh and proclaim judgement upon them. Instead, he attempted to flee on a boat to Tarshish. When a severe tempest threatened the ship, all the sailors prayed to their gods and then they proceeded to lighten the load. Jonah, however, went into the hold of the vessel where he lay down and fell asleep. The captain urged Jonah to call out to his God.
Rabbeinu Bachya (Kad Hakemach Kipuurim Aleph):
ויונה לא עשה כן אבל הצדיק עליו את הדין והיה בוטח בהקב"ה שיצילהו כשם שהוא מציל את הצדיקים כמו שכתוב (תהלים לד) רבות רעות צדיק וגו':
ויונה ירד אל ירכתי הספינה וישכב וירדם זה מוכיח שלא היתה כונתו רעה כי היה שוכב ונרדם כמי שלבו בטוח ולא היה לו פחד כלל. Jonah did not do this (pray) because he accepted the judgment (against him) and was confident that God would save him in the manner that He saves the righteous as it states (Psalms 34): "Many are the afflictions of the righteous, but the LORD delivers him out of them all..." "Jonah, meanwhile, had gone down into the hold of the vessel where he lay down and fell asleep." This proves that his (Jonah's) intention was not evil because he lied down and slept as one whose heart is confident, and he possessed no fear whatsoever...
Question:
He accepted his fate, but why was he certain that it was a good fate - hadn't he just disobeyed God's command? His acts clearly caused the tempest! How did he know that death wasn't coming? And how did he know his fate was sealed (for good or bad)? The righteous pray and perform worthy acts until the very end precisely because they eschew the notion of 'one's fate being sealed.'

And meanwhile Malbim says Yonah assumes God wants to kill him, and this way he'll have a quick, painless death that will spare the sailors on the deck.

It would help if you gave the source of this quote.

Rabeinu bichaye (on torah) holds if you have complete faith in God he'll save you. Even If you have sins.

The quoted text is from the paragraph 6 commenting on actions of Yonah. In the preceeding paragraphs Rabbeinu Bachya explains why Yonah acted this way and why he was at fault. To summarize, the intention of Yonah was not that a man can  run away from Hashem, because David already said in Tehilim 139:7-8:

Where can I escape from Your spirit? Where can I flee from Your presence? If I ascend to heaven, You are there; if I descend to Sheol, You are there too.

Rather he sought to run from Eretz Israel, where the spirit of prophecy is always present to Tarshish (Spain?), where the Glory of Hashem ('כבוד ה) is not revealed, so that he would no longer experience prophecy.
Hashem made him a messenger. The fact that he refused to be the messenger, his thought was good and intention for the sake of Heaven, because of humility and wholeness of his heart. Yonah made Kal vaChomer to the words of Moshe rabbeinu. As Hashem sent Moshe to Pharaoh (Shemos 3:10), Moshe also refused, Shemos 4:13:

But he said, “Please, O my lord, make someone else Your agent.” (i.e. make someone else Your agent, Literally “send through whomever You will send.”)

So, Yonah reasoned, if Moshe refused to be a messenger to take out Israel, the righteous, out of Mitzraim; so he, who was sent as a messenger to warn the evil-doers in Assyria - even more so was permitted to do.
If one asks, if his intention was good, why was he punished that in the end he was sent into the sea? Rabbeinu Bachya answers, that Yonah refused to warn the evil people of Ninveh, which was a command of HKBH. Because the righteous and the prophets are obligated by way of the Torah to warn the evil-doers, as we find in Yechezkel 3:18-19

If I say to someone wicked, ‘You shall die,’ and you do not give warning—you do not speak to warn them of their wicked course in order to save their life—then that wicked one shall die for their own iniquity, while from you I will require a reckoning for their blood. But if you do warn someone wicked, and they do not turn back from their wickedness and their wicked course, they shall die for their iniquity, while you will have saved your own life.

Yonah refused, that's why he was punished. Even if one asks, Yechezkel was sent to warn Israel, but Yonah was sent to warn a foreign nation, whom Yonah was not obligated to warn. Even in this case, since Hashem said, "Arise, go to Ninveh,...", as a command, it means that Hashem hoped that they would repent, and as a result Yonah had to warn them. His refusal was equivalent that he was fit to demand their punishment, not for their honor, but for that of Hashem. That's a problem that Yonah had not yet understood. Thus, Rabbeinu Bachya concludes that Yonah's refusal cannot be compared to that of Moshe, for Moshe was sent not to warn the evil Pharaoh, but to free Bnei Israel.
Hence, Yonah deserved punishment, however he had not yet realized it. Rabbeinu Bachya already showed, that Yonah acted on a faulty premise and has not yet realized his mistake. He thought that he could continue on the way to escape. That's why the captain of the ship, who was a very wise man, warned him in verse Yona 1:6, as Rabbeinu Bachya explains this warning:

Why are you asleap as the one whose heart is confident and without fear? Even if you are confident in your righteousness, you are obligated to beseach for mercy and pray, 'rise and call your G-d'.

The captain of the ship informed him that if one is in the midst of the trouble anywhere in this world, or the time of trouble came, one can save others and oneself with prayer, as the verse Tehilim 34:18 says:

They (the righteous) cry out, and Hashem hears, and saves them from all their troubles.

Perhaps, it is this advice of the captain that saved Yonah in this case. Because of his false premise, Yonah had not realized that death might be coming. As we know, Yonah was swallowed by the fish and spent 3 days inside the belly, bringing various reasons why he should be saved. Rabbeinu Bachya reads דגה meaning a dead fish. Only then Yonah realized his mistake, as we see from his prayer, Yonah 2:3

He said: In my trouble I called to  G-D, Who answered me; From the belly of Sheol I cried out, And You heard my voice.

